# How to read The Rise of the Elder Things Cultists text

Tags: eldritch-horror

The Cultists for The Rise of the Elder Things Ancient One have the following text

> If you pass the lore test, you free the victim's mind from the alien magic; defeat this Monster and gain 1 random Ally Asset from the deck.

[Elder Things Cultists](https://eldritchhorror.fandom.com/wiki/Elder_Things#Cultists)

Is the Cultists defeated if the lore test is passed?

Or do players still need to defeat the Cultists after passing the lore test to gain 1 random Ally asset? And should really be read as

> If you pass the lore test, you free the victim's mind from the alien magic; defeat this Monster **to** gain 1 random Ally Asset from the deck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to defeat the Cultist to gain the rewards if you pass the Horror Check.

Whenever fighting a monster, you have a Horror Check then a Strength Check. The Horror Check is usually a Will Test [image: Will Icon via eldritchhorror.fandom.com] but whenever fighting The Elder Things Cultists, it specifically asks for a Lore Test ([image: Lore Icon via eldritchhorror.fandom.com]-1). If you roll a success, you free the victim, defeat the Cultist, and gain a random Aly Asset from the assets deck. Thematically, this is the Ally you freed from The Elder Things grasp.

If you **fail** the Sanity Check, you take the difference in Sanity damage and move on to the Strenth Check [image: Strength Icon via eldritchhorror.fandom.com] to try and defeat the Cultist by brute force. Successes you roll deal damage to cultist, but if you defeat the Cultist this way you don't gain a random Ally Asset.

Comment: The thematic explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks for that :)